# how to populate textbox with new Row ID in windows form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm creating a windows form and currently in the process of creating the "create member" form.

Now i wish to show to the user inputting data what the new members ID will be. So i thought of trying to show the new row ID within a text box. So if we take the example below, when the form loads, the new member ID should be shown in the textbox
[image]

I've tried to attempt it below but having difficulty getting the result from the sqlCommand. Or maybe im going the wrong way around doing it ha

Can anyone see how i can apply the id upon load?

```
    private void frmAddMember_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineeringDB))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID=(SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM Users", connection))
            {
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@MYVALUE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (re.Read())
                {
                    txtMemberId.Text = // result from the SQLCommand but i dont know how to get it
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your workflow here. So: user creates new member -> you then want to show them that new member's id-> so you reload the form and try to get the last inserted id?

Comment: @Jedediah updated the question to show what im trying to acheive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access current row cells by indexing `DataReader` with columns names, like this `txtMemberId.Text = thisReader["UserID"]; //here you should do increment`. But honestly, generating `Id` in `select max(id) + 1` manner is odd, `GUIDs` nad `Autoinc integer` is more commonly used in our days.

Your `MAX+1` should looks like:

```
private void frmAddMember_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineeringDB))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(UserID), 0) + 1) as UserID FROM Users", connection))
            {
                SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (re.Read())
                {
                    txtMemberId.Text = re["UserID"].ToString();
```

Comment: perfect @agent5566 ! also as you mention the GUIDs and AutoInc, to tell you the truth, we are doing a group project in school and i got left with a mess of a database and only till friday to complete it since no else is going to bother haha so that explains the mess, i will in future take more time in design for my own work

Answer (score 0):

remove your autoinc id column and add a guid id col instead. then you can generate the Id on the client with Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ID column is being generated by the database (auto increment, etc...) just get the ID when you create the record.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User(FirstName) VALUES('bob')");
var id = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
txtMemberId.Text = id.ToString();
```